# Why are the component selectors inconsistent in angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm finding the component selector namings inconsistent:

```
<button md-button></button>
```

and

```
<input mdInput />
```

Are they or am I missing the logic behind it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is reported, you can follow progress here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3125

Comment: Thanks! I missed that report. Looks like there is logic behind it but is confusing at first sight.